# How to check two mule running status in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

Could anyone help me modify the below python code into a single return statement?

```
return any("is running" in x for x in response.splitlines()) <br>
return any("active (running)" in x for x in response.splitlines())
```

I tried my best but end up in getting "`SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just wrap your `"is running" in x for x in response.splitlines()` around `[]` like this: `any(["is running" in x for x in response.splitlines()])`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. will it help to check the second condition "active (running)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> return any("is running" or "active (running)" in x for x in response.splitlines())

This one works fine.